# What type of events are queued in the Poll stage of the NodeJS event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

So, recently, I have been trying to understand the Node.js event loop, and I am a bit confused by the **poll** stage.

In the [official guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/), it says that `retrieve new I/O events; node will block here when appropriate.`, however, it doesnt explain what would be the type of events/callbacks in the **poll** queue, how they are put into the queue, and who has the responsibility for queuing events in that stage.

I would appreciate if anyone could shed some light onto it.